# Datagridviewcomboboxcell wont hold selected value when clicking out of a cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Description = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
Description.Name = "Value";
Description.DataSource = comboBoxValues;
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Start = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
Start.Name = "Second Value";
dataGridView2.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { Start, Description });
DataTable dt = "table of values";
DataTable BindingTable = new DataTable();
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
     DataRow newRow = dt.Rows[rowIndex];
     DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
     DataGridViewComboBoxCell newComboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
     newComboCell.DisplayMember = leftColumn;
     newComboCell.ValueMember = rightColumn;
     newComboCell.ValueType = typeof(string);
     newComboCell.Value = newRow["Value"].ToString();
     newComboCell.DataSource = comboBoxValues;
     DataGridViewTextBoxCell newTextCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
     newTextCell.Value = newRow["SecondValue"];
     row.Cells.Add(newTextCell);
     row.Cells.Add(newComboCell);
     dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
     }
dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

Above is how I am generating the datagridview, and that all works great. for some reason when I click into the datagridviewcomboboxcell and change the selected value, I then click out of the cell and then the combobox will return to the 0th index.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are going to have to provide a better example of the problem. I recommend you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) … Often, creating the Minimal, Reproducible Example will help you reveal the problem and will certainly help anyone else testing your code.

Comment: In addition, I am question your comment… _”Above is how I am generating the datagridview, and that all works great.”_ ? the posted code could NOT possibly work… `DataTable dt = "table of values";`? … is not going to work because a `DataTable` is not a `string.` It may help to clarify your question and make an MRE that reproduces the problem. Not many will help if they have to add a bunch of missing code.

Comment: hey @JohnG, I would hope people would understand that a DataTable is in fact not a string, I do however use a method to fill that table, however Its nothing more than a sql query that fills it. also, I would like to clarify that this is infact a working way to build a datatable I generate several tables the same way it is only problem is the combobox defaulting back to the 0th index.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is difficult to understand from the posted code what you are trying to achieve. The posted code does not demonstrate the issue you describe. As I stated in my first comment, creating a MRE is usually a good process for two reasons… 1) often times this will help “you” find the problem and 2) if your MRE doesn’t work as expected, then post it for others to test. Others are more likely to help if they can recreate the problem from the posted code. Currently, the posted code is missing too much to work and will only lead to speculation and more questions. Good Luck.